# Upgrade from Raspberry Pi3 to Pi4 caused loss of USB drive partition

Tags: pi-4

I could see both partitions in Pi3, but now one has disappeared in Pi4 (using identical install steps).

Raspberry Pi 3

```
UUID               NAME        FSTYPE  SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL      MODEL
5A08901A088FF375   ├─sda2      ntfs    1.8T /home/pi/g Podcasts g
7C1A0E541A0E0BB8   └─sda3      ntfs    1.8T /home/pi/h Podcasts h
```

Raspberry Pi 4

```
UUID               NAME        FSTYPE  SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL      MODEL
5A08901A088FF375   ├─sda2      ntfs    1.8T /home/pi/g Podcasts g
<blank>            └─sda3              1.8T
```

A separate (but perhaps related) issue is the Pi4 mounted g drive is not readable. The ls command gives the following error:

```
reading directory '.': Input/output error
```

Neither of these were problems with Pi3.

Per Ingo request:

Raspberry Pi3 sudo blkid output (I kept text of all my outputs from my Pi3 installation just in case)

```
/dev/sda2: LABEL="Podcasts g" UUID="5A08901A088FF375" TYPE="ntfs" PTTYPE="atari" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="eaa6a54c-27ef-4939-ada9-a180797f6f24"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="Podcasts h" UUID="7C1A0E541A0E0BB8" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="08d467ff-46bf-4f19-a2d6-def43e50b34e"
```

Raspberry Pi4 sudo blkid output

```
/dev/sda2: LABEL="Podcasts g" UUID="5A08901A088FF375" TYPE="ntfs" PTTYPE="atari" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" 
/dev/sda3: PTTYPE="atari" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="08d467ff-46bf-4f19-a2d6-def43e50b34e"
```

findmnt /dev/sda3 has nothing (nothing to mount)
/etc/fstab is the default (no automount yet)

FYI these are generic os-lite installs with samba (I'm rebuilding my file server in Pi4 after successfully, but slowly, using it for week with Pi3)

Comment: `reading directory '.': Input/output error` that suggests the drive is ready to die, backup your information if you can.

Comment: It's not going to die ... this is a Pi4 issue. I have three separate 4tb drives each split into 2-2tb partitions, each with the same issue (just one hooked up for this question).

Comment: No doubt the USB on these things is poor to say the least, mine will not boot with my keyboard attached, so you already know your answer poor design.

Comment: Just to get an idea, please [Edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/121751/edit) your question and from the RasPi4 add the output of these commands to it: `sudo blkid` and `findmnt /dev/sda3` and `cat /etc/fstab`.

Answer (score 2):

The firmware on the external usb hard drives needed to ''get acquainted'' with the usb connectors on the pi4.

I have three different brand external usb drives, call them red (K/L) blue (g/h) and silver (i/M).
[image]

Blue only worked with my USB2 connector on my laptop, red and silver with my laptop USB3 connectors.

Blue connected solo to an outside USB (2.0) connector on the Pi4 gave the missing partition error of the original post. Blue connected to a middle USB (3.0) connector on the Pi4 gave no partitions (as expected).

Red connected to a middle USB (3.0) connector on Pi4 gave a similar missing partition error.

I connected red and blue to the outside (USB2) connectors on Pi4 and all the red and blue partitions appeared. I then connected red and silver to the middle USB (3.0) and blue to the outside USB (2.0) and all partitions appeared.
[image]

This also fixes the Input/Output error.

I don't recall any reboots or restarts being needed for this exercise.

Weird to say the least.